# Wrong number of NAs showed after removing certain amount

Tags: r, na

I'm quite new to R and while trying to randomly set values in a dataset as NA I got a little stuck and cannot really find the problem, maybe someone here might be able to help? It would be really apprecciated.

So I'm just trying things out with the ChickenWeight dataset in R and wanted to set 10% of the values in the variable weight as missing. However, when I look at a table of the NAs afterwards, there aren't 10% missing, but way less than this and I just don't understand why?

that's my code:

```
`data <- ChickWeight
p.mis <- length(data$weight)/10
missings <- data$weight[sample(data$weight, p.mis, replace = F)]
data[missings,1] <- NA
table(is.na(data$weight)) `
```

It should be about 58 NAs, seeing that length of data$weight is 578, but it just shows about 35 NAs, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should sample without replacement, so `replace = TRUE`.

Comment: @PaulH I think replace=FALSE was OK

Comment: You're absolutely right, guess I was sleeping.

Comment: You can also use the prodNA function provided in the `missForest` package. Here is a little code snippet: `temp<-prodNA(x = as.data.frame(data$weight), noNA=0.1)`  -------- `data$weight=temp$`data$weight``

Answer (score 1):

The indices that you used will not work.  What you need is:

```
data <- ChickWeight
p.mis <- length(data$weight)/10
missings <- sample(length(data$weight), p.mis, replace = F)
data[missings,1] <- NA
table(is.na(data$weight))
FALSE  TRUE 
  521    57
```

Comment: wow, that seems so simple that I feel kinda stupid now, haha, thanks a lot for the fast reply!